# Verilog: Changing a register or output depending on changes in multiple input signals

Tags: verilog, register

I am trying to output a 2 bit-number that indicates which input signal changed during the time span when "detection mode" is switched on by another input signal. The output is saved in a register.

Each time detection mode is switched off and on again, the output/register should be set to 0.

So the register depends on changes in multiple signals. The way I know of to react to signal changes is using always blocks. However, inside one always @* block reacting to any change, as I understood, it is not possible to differentiate between changes in different signals and react to each of them in a separate block, as always cannot be nested, and @negedge / @posedge is not synthesizable.

I do not use a clock, purely combinatorial logic, to limit complexity in the overall FPGA-Microcontroller system. Unless there is no other solution, this should not change.

**Edit on May 28, 2023**
The signals are independent from each other and use a one-wire data transmission protocol without a second clock line. The minimum period between signal changes is around 100ns. I prefer not to have to include a clock detection circuit.
Only one input is connected at a time. The aim of the circuit is to detect which input is connected.
**Edit end**

I have difficulties realizing this behaviour using only one `always` block (`always @*`). Using several `always` blocks, I run into the problem that one register cannot be set by several `always` blocks.
I could not find any hints on how implement this logic on stackexchange or elsewhere. I believe that maybe combinatorial logic with more registers could somehow lead to the desired result, but I am not sure how.

Neither do I understand how I can integrate the `always @Local_Mother1` and 2 blocks into the first `always` block and set the Signal Number inside that block correctly.

My code looks as follows, but results in an error (Only one `always` block can assign a given variable)

```verilog
input wire Local_Mother1, Local_Mother2; //The signals to be detected (only one signal may be connected)
            
input wire Steuerung;   //Used for controlling detection mode

reg r_LMCode[0:1]=0 ;   //Initialized at 0, this synthesizes using Lattice ICE40 - Signal number        
reg r_LMdetectmode=0;   //Initialized at 0, this synthesizes using Lattice ICE40 - Detection mode
        
//Handle the detection mode switch-on and off
always @(Steuerung) begin
    if (r_LMdetectmode==0) begin    //detection mode off

        if (Steuerung==1)   //This switches on detection mode
            r_LMdetectmode <= 1; 
            //r_LMCode <=0; //could be set here as well, but does not change the problem

    end else begin //Detection mode is on
        if (Steuerung==0) begin
            r_LMdetectmode <=0;     //Switch off detection mode
            r_LMCode <= 0;      //Signal Number set to 0 - gives an error!
        end
    end
end

always @(Local_Mother1) begin   //in case Signal 1 has changed
    if (r_LMdetectmode==1)
        r_LMCode <= 1;  //Set signal number to 1 if detect mode is on - error!
end
        
always @(Local_Mother2) begin   //in case Signal 2 has changed
    if (r_LMdetectmode==1)
        r_LMCode <= 2;  //Set signal number to 2 if detect mode is on - error!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage in doing this asynchronously, it doesn't reduce complexity. In fact it is [worse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571788/vhdl-k-map-reduced-characteristic-equation-fails/572184#572184) as you are inferring latches.

Here's a suggested synchronous solution - it assumes your inputs are already synchronous to the clock; if they are not they should be resynchronised. I've also assumed that the inputs are independent and the `r_LMCode` bits are also independent. (From edited question, only one input will be active at any time).

```
reg  r_Local_Mother1;
wire LM1_delta;
reg  r_Local_Mother2;
wire LM2_delta;
reg  [1:0] r_LMCode;
wire [1:0] LMCode_nxt;

// Set delta flag when the current input doesn't match the last
assign LM1_delta = r_Local_Mother1 ^ Local_Mother1;
assign LM2_delta = r_Local_Mother2 ^ Local_Mother2;

assign LMCode_nxt =   Steuerung 
                    // r_LMCode is sticky when set in detection mode
                    ? (r_LMCode | {LM2_delta, LM1_delta}) 
                    // Clear to 0 when ~Steuerung
                    : 2'b00; 

always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
  if (reset) begin
    r_LMCode        <= 2'b00;
    r_Local_Mother1 <= 1'b0;
    r_Local_Mother2 <= 1'b0;
  end else begin
    r_LMCode        <= LMCode_nxt;
    r_Local_Mother1 <= Local_Mother1;
    r_Local_Mother2 <= Local_Mother2;
  end
end
```

NB, this is just a suggestion, depending on your exact requirements (signal ordering etc) you may need to change it :)

Comment: Dear Awjlogan, I now realize that I can detect signal changes by comparing the current value to a saved last value of the signal. However, I do not understand the disadvantage to do this comparison every time any signal changes (when an always@* block is called) versus every time a clock advances. Is there an issue when signal changes occur very rapidly? Does the added information in the question (highlighted with edit) eliminate potential latch timing problems?

Comment: @DerGrisu - comparing to a previous value implies storage, ie, a latch or a clocked register (also the captured output). The information re. the minimum period is useful - you will be able to capture this with a clock >10 MHz (ie, very easy). Latches make timing harder, and tools will generally warn you when a latch is inferred - it's not usually what you want. Have a search for many articles on this topic :) Is there a reason you really want to do it this way?

Answer (score 2):

> I do not use a clock, purely combinatorial logic, to limit complexity
> in the overall FPGA-Microcontroller system.

Since your current attempts at implementing your design do not work, you should consider using a clock instead of trying to implement purely combinatorial logic.  You tagged this question with `register` and mention using registers several times.  The term [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_register) implies memory storage, which can be achieved with flip flops, latches, etc.  Latches have more timing limitations than flip flops for synthesis.

A good approach uses flip flops with clocks; refer to [synthesizable constructs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs) and your FPGA tool suite documentation.  Those show you good Verilog coding style for synthesis.